# Adobe Omniture For Android fails on trackAction

Tags: java, android, adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm having trouble with making Adobe Omniture work consistently with Android. I call trackAction at parts of the app, and at half of the time, it fails when I call it at app launch.

Just some info, I'm using the latest version of Omniture (4.11.0 at the time of this writing), and I added the 4.11.0 jar file under app/libs folder and I added ADMobileConfig.json file under app/assets.

For build.gradle file, the minimum SDK is set 19 and target SDK is set to 20.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

This is the message that I got when I launch it:

08-09 15:13:22.096 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Unable to get package to pull application name. (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.097 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Unable to get package to pull application version. (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.100 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Unable to get package to pull application version code. (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.107 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Error getting device resolution. (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.107 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Error getting device carrier. (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.114 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Analytics - Error registering network receiver (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.114 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Null context when attempting to read config file (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.115 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Null context when attempting to read config file (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.116 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Unable to pull visitorID from shared preferences. (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.117 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Lifecycle - Issue loading persisted lifecycle data
08-09 15:13:22.148 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Error getting cache directory. (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.148 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Error getting cache directory. (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.148 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Config - Error getting cache directory. (Config - No Application Context (Application context must be set prior to calling any library functions.))

08-09 15:13:22.158 29529-30479/com.example.application E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:30199: (2) open(//ADBMobileDataCache.sqlite) -

08-09 15:13:22.181 29529-30479/com.example.application E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database 'ADBMobileDataCache.sqlite'.
                                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
                                                                       at com.adobe.mobile.AbstractDatabaseBacking.openOrCreateDatabase(AbstractDatabaseBacking.java:47)
                                                                       at com.adobe.mobile.AbstractDatabaseBacking.initDatabaseBacking(AbstractDatabaseBacking.java:68)
                                                                       at com.adobe.mobile.AnalyticsWorker.(AnalyticsWorker.java:77)
                                                                       at com.adobe.mobile.AnalyticsWorker.sharedInstance(AnalyticsWorker.java:64)
                                                                       at com.adobe.mobile.RequestBuilder.buildAndSendRequest(RequestBuilder.java:117)
                                                                       at com.adobe.mobile.AnalyticsTrackAction.trackAction(AnalyticsTrackAction.java:38)
                                                                       at com.adobe.mobile.Analytics$2.run(Analytics.java:81)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

08-09 15:13:22.181 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Analytics - Unable to open database (unknown error (code 14): Could not open database).

08-09 15:13:22.181 29529-30479/com.example.application E/ADBMobile: ADBMobile Error : Analytics - Unable to get tracking queue size due to an unopened database (null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the error, it seems that you didn't set the application context on the activity's onCreate method:

```
Config.setContext(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: I found out that I added this in the application class, rather than the Launch Activity, which is what causing it to fail inconsistently. This helped me solve the issue. Omniture is now tracking consistently!  Thank you!